# Email address check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I think many people have done some similar development tasks before:

I would like to check the people's email address whether only match @tomtom.com or @stream.com.

Currently, I have two solutions in my mind:

1. Using `indexof()` function

   ```
   var checkTomTomEmail=eo.data.username.indexOf("@tomtom.com");
   var checkStreamEmail=eo.data.username.indexOf("@stream.com");


   if (checkTomTomEmail >0 || checkStreamEmail >0 )
   {
       //Run the login code
   }


   Else 
   {
       //Please login with your tomtom or stream email 
   }
   ```
2. Using match

   ```
   var patt1=/@tomtom.com/gi;
   var patt2=/@stream.com/gi;
   var checkTomTomEmail=eo.data.username.match(patt1);
   var checkStreamEmail=eo.data.username.match(patt2);


   if(indexOf(checkTomTomEmail)> 1 ||indexOf (checkStreamEmail)>1)
   {
       //Login 
   }
   ```

I still think I do not consider all the detail yet. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Does this have to be javascript? Are there security concerns?  If someone wanted to bypass this its trivial..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps if people are only allowed to enter emails for those two addresses you should only collect the username and then allow them to choose @tomtom.com or @stream.com using radiobuttons.

If you still want to go the javascript route then your regex can be combined into a single statement

```
var emailPatt=/@(tomtom|stream).com/gi;

if(emailPatt.test(eo.data.username))
{
    //Login 
}
```

Comment: that will too much customziation in our vendor system. THansk Evil Anday, what do u think the match solution?

Answer (score 2):

How about this...

```
var emailRegex = /^([0-9a-z])+@(tomtom|stream)\.com$/ig;
if (emailRegex.test(emailRegex)) {
    // Login
}
```

Instead of performing a .match(...) - Which you'll get a string back, we can perform a .test(...) to see if anything matches.

This pattern guarantees the following:

1. The "username" part of the email address must at least have a SINGLE character (For example, a@stream.com)
2. Username must be composed of a digit or an alphabet (Upper/Lower case - Doesn't matter because of the /i at the end)
3. Input must contain the entire email address without leading or tailing spaces. For example, "  user@tomtom.com " will fail, it'll only accept "user@tomtom.com".)

You can customize this further by, saying, making sure username must have at least 3 characters, you can use underscore or dashes in the email address, etc.

To answer your question, both solutions won't work. Reasons:

1. User can enter "tom@tomtom.com Hello", and it'll pass both of your validation.
2. Specifically on solution #2, the dot '.' is a Regex-reserved character, it means it'll match anything, so, if the user enters " @tomtom1com", it'll pass...

More on Regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html